# convert 240V to two 120 circuits

Tags: electrical, wiring

Electrician wired a two 30AMP breaker to feed a future mini split. He brought 2 hot wires (Black) and one ground (green) to a disconnect box.

Now I am abandoning the mini split project and want to convert the current configuration to two 120V 20Amp each.

How?

Comment: **Are both hots black?** If so, you can't use them (as is) for 120V. However, that would mean you are in conduit, in which case you can *add* a white wire. Or two whites for two circuits (one paired with each black hot). If you actually have black/white/green then you have a cable and can turn it into 1 120V circuit.

Comment: Does this circuit have NM cable from the panel to a box and then conduit from this box to an outside box near where the minisplit was to be installed? If so, what type of cable is this, i.e., size and number of insulated conductors?

Comment: Is this circuit run entirely in conduit, or partly in conduit and partly in cable?

Answer (score 3):

Edit for visibility - If you have two black wires, you aren't allowed by code to repurpose a black wire to a neutral.

You get 120v from 240v by using one hot and a neutral.  Circuits that only need 240v like an AC can be run using only hots, but if the appliance uses 120v and 240v like a range/stove then you need three wires + ground.

So, unfortunately, the answer is that you can turn your circuit into a single 20A 120v circuit (if one wire is white), but without that third wire, you can't divide it into two.

If the wires are in conduit, you can pull a third wire as long as the conduit has space.  Code dictates how many wires can be run in conduit, so that's another thing you would need to check.

Comment: Not with 2 black wires, though.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica, I forgot you're not supposed to use a black as a neutral.  Wrapping the ends with white tape is pretty low on the chart of electrical sins, but it wouldn't pass code.

Comment: @JPhi1618 But if it is actually two blacks then it is conduit and easy to resolve.

Comment: Right, because nobody makes #10 cable that is black-black-green.  The only black-black cable I've ever heard of is SE, which has bare *neutral* weirdly enough, and no ground, because it's for service entrances where ground isn't established yet.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica, Yea, little reading comprehension fail from me.  I saw 30A and assumed it was orange #10 romex.

Comment: White **or grey/gray/slate,** for neutral, given conduit (two blacks) but the question of whether the entire run is in conduit or not needs to be answered to determine feasibility of that.